# How to fix 'is.character(x) is not TRUE' error in Qualtrics package

Tags: r, qualtrics

I am attempting to fetch survey results via API using package `qualtRics` and command `fetch_survey`. `fetch_survey`, however, only returns the following error:

```
Error in parse_vector(x, col_factor(levels, ordered, include_na), na = na,  : 
  is.character(x) is not TRUE
```

This technique has worked for me before. I am running RStudio Version 1.1.463 and `qualtRics` package version has been updated today. My API access is valid and correct, and my survey ID is also correct.

```
install.packages("qualtRics")
library(qualtRics)
qualtrics_api_credentials("MY_API_KEY", "MY_BASE_URL", install = TRUE)
qualtRics::fetch_survey("MY_SURVEY_ID")
```

My expected results are an output of the survey, my actual result is the listed error above.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but only when passing certain parameters to fetch_survey.  I.e. fetch_survey(survey_id) works fine, but fetch_survey(survey_id, unanswer_recode = "0") doesn't.

Comment: I dug into this further this morning, and the problem disappeared when I upgraded R from 3.5.2 to 3.6.1